# Python - Loop over all instances of multiple lists

Tags: python

Is there a better way for looping over every combination of multiple lists in Python? For example...

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [6,7,8]

for i in list1:
   for j in list2:
      print(str(i) + ", " + str(j))

1, 6
1, 7
1, 8
2, 6
2, 7
2, 8
3, 6
3, 7
3, 8
4, 6
4, 7
4, 8
```

I ask because I would like to break out of both loops once a value is found. I do not want to use a bool flag to break out of the top level loop. All answers I have seen so far say to use zip, but that is not the same thing. zip would produce the following.

```
1, 6
2, 7
3, 8
```

If you use map, you get the following, which is also not what I am looking for.

```
1, 6
2, 7
3, 8
4, None
```

Comment: Have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)!

Comment: `itertools.product`

Comment: What is the value you're looking for? Like `i == <x>` and `j == <y>`? What are `<x>` and `<y>` in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like so:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [6,7,8]
find_this_value = (1, 8)

found_value = False
for permutation in itertools.product(list1, list2):
    if permutation == find_this_value:
        found_value = True
        break

if found_value:
    pass  # Take action
```

`itertools.product` returns a generator with all of the possible permutations of the 2 lists. Then, you simply iterate over those, and search until you find the value you want.

Comment: I like this answer the best because it gives the solution in the most straight forward way. However, I like the answers that suggest using a function as well. They hold to the single responsibility principle and solves the problem. Maybe a combination of both is the best solution...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a list comprehension

```
[(x, y) for x in [1,2,3,4]
 for y in [6,7,8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `itertools.product` as suggested in another answer, you can wrap it in a function and return:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [6,7,8]

def findNumbers(x, y):
    for i in list1:
       for j in list2:
          print(str(i) + ", " + str(j))
          if (x, y) == (i, j):
              return (x, y)
```

Output:

```
>>> findNumbers(2, 7)
1, 6
1, 7
1, 8
2, 6
2, 7
(2, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know where you were in the scan when the break condition arose, you can use  list comprehensions and `enumerate` together

```
for i,a,j,b in [ x+y for x in enumerate([11,12,13,14]) for y in enumerate([16,17,18]) ]:
    print( i,a,j,b)
    if a==13 and b==17: break
print(i,j) # get 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `product` function.

You can read more in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression

```
import itertools
print (list(itertools.product(list1, list2)))
# [(1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to see `product` used in a simple code.

- In this case `product` is an iterator that returns elements of the cross-product of `list1` and `list2` one at a time.
- Within the `for`-loop we watch for the appearance of a certain pair, and `break` out of the loop if and when we encounter it.

--

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = [6,7,8]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for i, j in product(list1, list2):
...     if (i,j)==(2,7):
...         print (i,j)
...         break
...     
2 7
```